# Property 'create' does not exist on type { new (fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag | undefined):File; prototype: File}

Tags: typescript, mongodb, file, mongoose

I'm trying to create a file-sharing app using Multer, Cloudinary, Typescript, and Mongoose.

When I'm trying to save the files uploaded by users and the data like **Filename**, **filesize**, **Secure_url** & **format** to `mongoose` database it keeps throwing me this ***Typescript*** error `Property 'create' does not exist on type`.

> Here's the code

**File path `server/routes/files.ts`**

```
import express from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'
import {UploadApiResponse, v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary'

const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({})

router.post
let upload = multer({
    storage
})

router.post("/upload", upload.single("myFile"), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.file)
            return res.status(400).json({message: "Hey there! We need the file"})

        console.log(req.file);

        //storing the file in the variable "uploadedFile" and getting the api response from UploadApiResponse
        let uploadedFile: UploadApiResponse;

        try {
            //it's an async call. Here we're uploading the file
            uploadedFile = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
                folder: "shareme",
                resource_type: "auto"
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)

            return res.status(400).json({message: "Cloudinary Error"})
        }

        const {originalname} = req.file 
        const {secure_url, bytes, format} = uploadedFile 

       constructor of the model and 2) Create method
        const file = await File.create({
            filename: originalname,
            sizeInBytes: bytes,
            secure_url,
            format,
        });
        res.status(200).json(file);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).json({message: "Server Error :( "})
    }
})

export default router
```

**`server/model/File.ts`**

```
import mongoose,{Document}  from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const fileSchema = new Schema({
        filename: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        secure_url: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        format: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        sizeInByte: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        sender: {
            type: String,
        },
        receiver: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);


// Interface  "IFile" has all the properties of mongoose document
interface IFile extends Document{
    filename: string,
    secure_url: string,
    sizeInByte: string,
    format: string,
    sender?: string,
    receiver?: string,
}

//typescript  IFILE interface
export default mongoose.model<IFile>("File", fileSchema)
```

**`server/config/db.ts`**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!, {
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Connection Error", error.message);
    }

    //checking connection status
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    //if connected to database
    if (connection.readyState>=1) {
        console.log("connected to database");
        return;
    }
    connection.on("error",()=>console.log("connection failed"));
}

export default connectDB;
```

**`server/server.ts`**

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors'
import connectDB from "./config/db";
import fileRoute from "./routes/files"
import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary'

const app = express()
dotenv.config()

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name:process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_CLOUD,
    api_key:process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret:process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
})

connectDB()


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

app.use("/api/files", fileRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is listening on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --clear server.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.26.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.10",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "tsc": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

[image: I've attached an error photo]

I've no idea what I'm missing here. I'm not able to store the data(Files) in mongoose which are extracted from `multer` (Grabbing the original name of the file) & `Cloudinary` (Grabbing the uploaded file). And this is my first time using mongoos.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you need to import the File from model in the path `server/routes/files.ts`

import File from '../models/File.ts'

and then in the same path `server/routes/files.ts`

change: constructor of the model and 2) Create method

```
const file = await File.create({
filename: originalname,
sizeInBytes: bytes,
secure_url, format, });

to: const file = new File({
    filename: originalname,
    sizeInBytes: bytes,
    secure_url,
    format,});
    res.status(200).json(file);
```